# How to get value corresponding to the id

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I want to get "id" and it's corresponding value in anchor tag.

```
<li id="1" class="list">
    <a class="tim">This is Link1</a>
<li id="2" class="list">
    <a class="tim">This is Link2</a>
<li id="3" class="list">
    <a class="tim">This is Link3</a>
```

I have tried with below code:

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
response = HtmlResponse(url="some url", body=htmltext, encoding='utf8')

for x in response.css('li::attr(id)').extract():
    item = {}
    item['id'] = x
    item['value'] = x.css('a.tim::text').extract()
```

but it gives me an `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'css'` for the last line.

Comment: What type of object is `response` here? Are you using a library, what library is that?

Comment: I am using scrapy request

Comment: Right, I attempted to add something of a [mcve] to the question, so people can actually reproduce the issue and help. *Context is important* when asking a question.

Comment: @Martijn, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`extract()` extracts the value of the attribute, so you have a list of attribute values:

```
>>> response.css('li::attr(id)').extract()
['1', '2', '3']
```

Don't extract then loop, you need to select the `li` elements (not the attribute) and then loop over the `Selector` instances instead:

```
for x in response.css('li[id]'):  # li elements that have an id attribute
    item = {
        'id': x.css('::attr(id)').extract_first(),
        'value': x.css('a.tim::text').extract_first(),
    }
```

This produces a dictionary with the required `id` and `value` attributes:

```
>>> for x in response.css('li[id]'):  # li elements that have an id attribute
...     item = {
...         'id': x.css('::attr(id)').extract_first(),
...         'value': x.css('a.tim::text').extract_first(),
...     }
...     print(item)
...
{'id': '1', 'value': 'This is Link1'}
{'id': '2', 'value': 'This is Link2'}
{'id': '3', 'value': 'This is Link3'}
```